# Question on Poincaré Lemma for Rectangles Proof

Tags: differential-forms

[image]

This is the first part of the proof that my differential forms textbook (*Differential Forms* by Guillemin and Haine) gives for the Poincaré Lemma for Rectangles. Everything up to the last math line $\left(\int \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}dx_i\right)$ I understand. However, I have a few questions on it. First, why does it become $f(x)$ and not $f_i(x)$? This could be a typo but I want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something. Second, why is $f_i$ supported on $U$? Nowhere before this point have I seen mention of what $U$ is. Finally, and this is the more important question, the idea is that since $\mbox{supp}(\mu) \subset \mbox{int}(Q)$ then the end points $a_i, b_i \notin \mbox{supp}(\mu)$ and thus $f_i(a_i) = f_i(b_i) = 0$? This isn't explained super well so I wanted to make sure. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Yes, that is a typo; it should be $f_i$.  Where is $U$ defined? I don't see it in what you've copied. I assume $U$ is an open set containing the support of $\mu$ (which, in particular, is the union of the supports of the $f_i$).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the clarification! That's part of what I'm confused about, they never explicitly define $U$ (at least for this part), so I have no idea